# can't set default selected option using value

Tags: javascript, html, selection, select-options

I make dropdown using select option tag.
Now I confused about how to custom the default selected option.
I want to set the default selected option for this option
uu

I've tried using "selected" attribute but it doesn't work when I set the value="uu".

```
<div>
<select class="form-control" id="c" name="c"  required>
    <option value="u" selected>uu</option>
    <option value="m">mm</option>
    <option value="n" >nn</option>
</select>
</div>
```

here is the result
[result set value="uu"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqZpa.png)

But if i set the value to value="" it works fine.

```
<div>
<select class="form-control" id="c" name="c"  required>
    <option value="" selected>uu</option>
    <option value="m">mm</option>
    <option value="n" >nn</option>
</select>
</div>
```

here is the result, it can show the option uu
[result set value=""](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djFlY.png)

maybe there is something that i should do to fix this? thankyou

Comment: Please don't make multiple user and post the same question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75529279/why-select-option-cannot-selected-which-are-contained-value

Comment: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn’t Work”?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616/289905) _“It doesn’t work”_ isn’t a problem statement and is meaningless without knowing your _desired_ results and your _actual_ results.

Comment: @SebastianSimon i mean 'it doesn't work' when i set  the value="uu" can't bring up the uu select option

Comment: when i set the value="uu" the result appears like this https://ibb.co/y00v4WY

Comment: but if i set the value="" the option can appears correctly like this https://ibb.co/mhv6d3X

Comment: Did you apply some javascript on it? It's working fine

Comment: Inspect your select and see what's the issue it's difficult to understand like this.

Comment: @Nisha I use JavaScript but I don't call anything about the select option

Comment: @Nisha i inspect the select but there is nothing show in console

Comment: @tugas2023 What do you mean _“there is nothing”_? This is an element. What does the element look like in the **Inspector** / **Elements** tab?

Answer (score 0):

It's showing uu here.

```html
 <div>
        <select class="form-control" id="c" name="c" required>
            <option value="u" selected>uu</option>
            <option value="m">mm</option>
            <option value="n">nn</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```